# Является ли окказионализмом словосочетание "разлуки жижа"?

Tags: общие-вопросы, терминология

Контекст:
"Подступай
К глазам,
Разлуки жижа,
Сердце
Мне
Сантиментальностью расквась!".

Answer (score 3):

**Из Википедии**: ***Окказионали́зм*** (от лат. occasionalis «случайный» ← occasio) — индивидуально-авторский неологизм, созданный поэтом или писателем согласно существующим в языке словообразовательным моделям и использующийся исключительно в условиях данного контекста, как лексическое средство художественной выразительности или языковой игры. Окказионализмы обычно не получают широкого распространения и не входят в словарный состав языка[1].

В Вашем случае ***разлуки жижа*** - это обычная **метафора**.

**Из Википедии:** ***Мета́фора*** — слово или выражение, употребляемое в переносном значении, в основе которого лежит сравнение неназванного предмета или явления с каким-либо другим на основании их общего признака.

Answer (score 2):

Разлуки жижа - это метафорический **перифраз** (или перифраза) - описательный оборот вместо слова "слёзы".

А вот вся фраза - *Подступай к глазам, разлуки жижа, сердце мне сантиментальностью расквась!*- это развёрнутая метафора.

Есть у Маяковского в этом стихотворении и олицетворение:

*Париж бежит, провожая меня...*

Есть эпитет: *во всей невозможной красе*. А вот окказионализма нет.